# here i am finding a reason for the given explanation in this code

Tags: python

```
class Circle():
     pi=3.14
     def __init__(self,radius=1):
          self.radius = radius 
          self.area = radius * radius * Circle.pi
     def set_radius(self,new_radius):
         self.radius = new_radius
         self.area = new_radius * new_radius * self.pi
c=Circle()
print("radius",c.radius)
```

prints the radius= 1

```
c.set_radius(5)
print('radius:',c.radius)
```

prints the radius =5

This code will run without any errors.

```
Circle().set_radius(10)
print('radius:',c.radius)
```

prints the radius value as 5 but not 10

when i tried the above line ,the code ran without any errors but didn't get same output

here i am trying to use the line without using the 'c'variable instead i wanna use the class. why it doesn't work?

Comment: Your original version of the code didn't run because of what appeared to be a typo, so I fixed that, but the code still doesn't print anything at any point.  It's not at all clear what difference you're trying to debug.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't call class methods at instantiation aside from `__init__`. The code `Circle().set_radius(5)` returns an object of NoneType. What you should do is just `Circle(5)`, which sets the radius during init.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @TannerDolby, this is python. there is no `new` syntax for instantiating new objects.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth too much time on the JS side lately. Removed my incorrect statement. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is done correctly up until your last statement. Let's break down your last bit of code to see what's happening here.

```py
Circle().set_radius(10)
#----------------------------------#
Circle()                           # Create a new circle
        .set_radius(10)            # and get the value it returns when you call this function
```

There are a couple issues with this statement, so let's go through what I see so far...

1. In this second instance, you never save the reference to the new `Circle()`, so that value will be lost forever. what I think you were trying to do here was to use the `Circle` that you had already instantiated, `c` and set *its* radius to 10.
2. When you `print` out your old `Circle` `c`, you haven't changed it from before, so I wouldn't expect the radius to change.

Let's try this again, with these things in mind...

```py
class Circle():
     pi=3.14
     def __init__(self,radius=1):
          self.radius = radius 
          self.area = radius * radius * self.pi # fixed this line to use self.pi
     def set_radius(self,new_radius):
         self.radius = new_radius
         self.area = new_radius * new_radius * self.pi
c=Circle()
print("radius",c.radius)
# >>> radius: 1

c.set_radius(5)
print('radius:',c.radius)
# >>> radius: 5

c.set_radius(10)          # This is where we got confused before.
print('radius:',c.radius)
# >>> radius: 10
```